# Angular raise Error in a view with Internet Explorer

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, typescript

I'm writing an application using `aps.net`, `mvc 5`, `angular js` and `typescript`.

In the layout file I added the ng-app name using `<html ng-app='myApp'>` but I added the external js files, result of the typescript comilation, in just a few of the views.

Running the application in debug mode from visual studio 2013 and internet explorer, I receive the following error:

```
/Scripts/angular.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

This happens when I hope views without angular controllers, but I don't receive messages when the javascript files with the angular code is loaded. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked off each recommendation from [this article](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)? Notably, the `id="ng-app"` and namespace declarations

Comment: thanks, I have checked, but it's of no help, the problem happens with ie 11 in windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

i think what is happening over here is when your route which don't have js files the angular bootstraps the DOM and try searching for myApp but since there is no angular.module named myApp is decalred it throws an error.
 what you can do is instead of keeping the ng-app in layout page keep in the routes where you require angular to bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

you probably did `angular.module('myApp')` which is used to get an existing module. You need to do `angular.module('myApp',[])` to create the module.

Comment: I have looked better, but the problem happens in the pages where i don't have any angular code, and works fine with pages with its own controller

Comment: files where you have `<html ng-app='myApp'>` *must* have the code I mentioned to create the module